# Android - Unexpected layout of the AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, kotlin, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I try to add an AutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter in the fragment.

**Question is** that there is an empty space in the bottom of the drop down list.
The empty space seems to be related to the result: more results, bigger empty space.

Here is my code:

**AutoCompleteTextViewAdapter.kt**

```
class AutoCompleteTextViewAdapter(private val c: Context, @LayoutRes private val layoutResource: Int, private val nameList: Array<NameList>) :
ArrayAdapter<NameList>(c, layoutResource, nameList) {

var filteredNames: List<NameList> = listOf()

override fun getCount(): Int = filteredNames.size


override fun getItem(position: Int): NameList = filteredNames[position]

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(layoutResource, null, false)
    view.tvId.text = filteredNames[position].id.toString()
    view.tvName.text = filteredNames[position].name

    return view
}

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence?, filterResults: FilterResults) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            filteredNames = filterResults.values as List<NameList>

            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val queryString = charSequence?.toString()?.toLowerCase()

            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values =
                nameList.filter {
                    it.name.toLowerCase().contains(queryString.toString()) || it.id.toString().contains(queryString.toString())
                }
            return filterResults
        }
    }
}
```

**item_list.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvId"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvId" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/name_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapWords"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Fragment.kt**

```
val Names = arrayOf( NameList(1001,"David"), NameList(1002, "Johnson"), NameList(1013, "Kevin"))
val adapter = AutoCompleteTextViewAdapter(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(),  R.layout.item_list, Names)

val textView = binding.Name as AutoCompleteTextView
textView.threshold = 1
textView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height of the constraint layout to `wrap_content` in **item_list.xml**.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/margin">
```

Comment: It doesn't work by changing the height. But I try to use LinearLayout instead of ConstraintLayout and it works! Anyway, thanks for your help!